# Probability theory inequality relating r.v. with expected value

Tags: probability, inequality, expected-value

I am trying to self-study probability theory from materials which can be found [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-041-probabilistic-systems-analysis-and-applied-probability-fall-2010/index.htm). One of the problems contains one inequality in its solution that is completely non-obvious to me.

The problem is as follows (source [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-041-probabilistic-systems-analysis-and-applied-probability-fall-2010/exams/MIT6_041F10_final_s09_sol.pdf), problem 1A):
Let $\{X_n\}$ be a sequence of i.i.d random variables taking values in the interval $[0, 0.5]$. Show that if $\mathbf{E}[X^2_n]$ converges to $0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, then $X_n$ converges to $0$ in probability.

The solution is as follows:
Given $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbf{E}[X^2_n] = 0$, it implies $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbf{E}[X_n] = 0$ and $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathrm{var}(X_n) = 0$. Hence, one has
$$\begin{align} \mathrm{P}(|X_n - 0| \geq \epsilon) &\leq \mathrm{P}(|X_n - \mathbf{E}[X_n]| \geq \epsilon/2) + \mathrm{P}(|\mathbf{E}[X_n] - 0| \geq \epsilon/2) \\ &\leq \frac{\mathrm{var}(X_n)}{(\epsilon/2)^2} + \mathrm{P}(|\mathbf{E}[X_n] - 0| \geq \epsilon/2) \rightarrow 0\end{align} $$

I think I understand why $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbf{E}[X^2_n] = 0$ implies $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbf{E}[X_n] = 0$ and $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathrm{var}(X_n) = 0$, as well as the second inequality and why it equals $0$ as $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}$ is taken. What I completely don't understand is where does the first inequality come from and why it is correct:

$$\mathrm{P}(|X_n - 0| \geq \epsilon) \leq \mathrm{P}(|X_n - \mathbf{E}[X_n]| \geq \epsilon/2) + \mathrm{P}(|\mathbf{E}[X_n] - 0| \geq \epsilon/2)$$

Any help in the form of proofs or links to sources is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: The result follows directly from Markov's inequality, i.e.,
$$
\mathsf{P}(X_n>\epsilon)=\mathsf{P}\!\left(X_n^2>\epsilon^2\right)\le \frac{\mathsf{E}X_n^2}{\epsilon^2}\to 0
$$
as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: As pointed out by @d.k.o., the result only requires Markov inequality.In regards to your doubt, note that if $S < a$ and $T < b$ then $S + T < a+b,$ so $S + T \geq a+b$ implies that either $S \geq a$ or $T \geq b$ (now apply this with $X = T = S$ and $a = b = \epsilon / 2$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Letting $\mu\equiv \mathbf{E}[X_n]$, by the triangle inequality we have

$$|X_n - 0|\leq |X_n - \mu|+|\mu - 0|\\
\implies \{X_n:|X_n - 0| \geq \epsilon\}\subseteq  \{X_n:|X_n - \mu|+|\mu - 0|\geq \epsilon\}\\
\subseteq \{X_n:|X_n - \mu|\geq \epsilon/2\}\cup \{X_n:|\mu - 0|\geq \epsilon/2\},$$

so by monotonicity of the probability measure and Boole's inequality, we have $$P(\{X_n:|X_n - 0| \geq \epsilon\})\leq P\left(\{X_n:|X_n - \mu|\geq \epsilon/2\}\cup \{X_n:|\mu - 0|\geq \epsilon/2\} \right)\\
\leq P\left(\{X_n:|X_n - \mu|\geq \epsilon/2\}\right)+P\left(\{X_n:|\mu - 0|\geq \epsilon/2\} \right).\\$$

Comment: Great answer, this is the level of detail I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: @linkz of course, no prob